# SQL query to fetch employees only from IT DEPT but there are common employess who are in IT and CSE Dept

Tags: sql

```
EmpID Dept Name
1     IT Venkat
2     CSE MAhesh
1     CSE Venkat
```

Comment: Read urgently read [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and **learn** from it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select an employee who only works for IT and does not work for another department, use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE t1 WHERE DEPT = 'IT'
and not exists (select 'x' from TABLE t2 where t1.name = t2.name where t2.Dept not like 'IT')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from emp 
where emp_ID not in (select emp_ID 
                     from emp 
                     where dept in ('CSE'));
```

This query solved the problem.

On executing it I got the employees who are working only in IT dept but not working in CSE dept

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DEPT = 'IT'`

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. but I want the employee who only works for the Dept IT and not CSE

Comment: Pls select it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: but I want the employee who only works for the Dept IT and not CSE

Comment: that query gives you the output for IT as per the question.